# Can I cause an exception in C++ if I lose data on a cast?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I'm working on a legacy C product that has lots of castings and potential losses of data - casting from int to short kind of stuff. In Visual Studio, is there a way to cause an exception if this loss of data happens, or do I need to fill my code with asserts?

Comment: To avoid data loss in type casting you can use SafeInt Library. Please see the following link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd570023.aspx

Comment: @Naseef: Those functions don't **prevent** data loss, they complain about data loss. But it's a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not have in language features to support throwing exceptions on lossy conversions.  If you use brace initialization, as of C++11, the compiler is required to let you know about possibly-narrowing conversions, but that doesn't mean a conversion is narrowing **in practice** (i.e. at runtime).

The best solution to something like this is to either write your own library to do this, or to use one that already exists, such as [SafeInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd570023.aspx).